# unable to see master pages while adding a .aspx in the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to add a .aspx page in the project , but while adding the .aspx page i am not getting the option to choose existing master pages. I remember long back i used to get that option to select the master page.

Can someone let me know which option i am missing , or do i need to manually do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe the steps of how you are trying to add the page now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adding a new Page, or a new Content Page?

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2010. Choose **"Web Form Master Page"**, you see a new dialog box to select your master page.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong. If you want to add .aspx page (as Content page) then checked the `[ ] Select Master Page` checkbox at **Add new item dialog**.

Comment: thanks i got it now , i have to select webcontentform.in order to get that option